# pagePathLevel only number GAPI

Tags: google-analytics, google-api-js-client

I have filter

```
'ga:pagePathLevel1==/post/',
```

And this back me result as i expected

```
/post/125/asdd
/post/8784/assd
/post/asdasd/asdsd
```

But now i want ot filter result and get url only if pagePath2 is number, for example i was try this

```
'ga:pagePathLevel1==/post/ && ga:pagePathLevel2==/[^0-9]/',
```

Output should be:

```
/post/128/asdd
/post/8784/assd
```

But looks that regax is not good or not allowed here? Output is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For regex match, you need to use =~ instead of ==

Comment: Plus, the regexp should be ^\/[0-9]+\/$

Comment: Thank you this is working `'ga:pagePathLevel1==/post/ && ga:pagePathLevel2=~^\/[0-9]+\/$',`